# Silverlight Application in VS2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, silverlight

can any one tell me how to create a silver light application in VS2008

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to install **[Silverlight tools for VS2008](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=9442b0f2-7465-417a-88f3-5e7b5409e9dd&displaylang=en)** after installing **[Service pack for Visual Studio](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=FBEE1648-7106-44A7-9649-6D9F6D58056E&displaylang=en)**. Then you can create a new silverlight application in the IDE. Download **[Silverlight Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/)** for a collection os silverlight controls, components and utilities.

File-->New-->Project

Under your preferred language you can see Silverlight and Choose Silverlight application inside Visual Studio installed templates.

You can also use **[Expression blend](http://www.microsoft.com/expression/products/Blend_Overview.aspx)** to create Silverlight applications.